# How to update state in parent component with data taken from child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

As obvious as the title states it ain't.

I have a MenuContainer class component with a table of menuList items, which I pass as props to a child functional component, that maps it to another child element, which spits out a menu. That's nothing fancy.
The menu renders only {icon} from props.
In this parent container I also have another child element called ItemName, which should pass itemName props from the state (empty string by default).

The tricky part is that the value of this.state.itemName should be updated with the {name} of whatever menu item I hover the mouse over in the Menu/MenuItem component.
So, MenuItem components are rendered with icons only, and when I hover over them, I need the {name} (from menuList table) to be displayed in ItemName component.

**Parent - MenuContainer**

```
class MenuContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      itemName: ''
    };
  };

  menuList = [
    {name: 'chat', icon: 'talking-heads'},
    {name: 'people', icon: 'loads-of-heads'},
    {name: 'settings', icon: 'cogwheel'},
    {name: 'potatoes', icon: 'one-huge-potato'}
  ];

  getItemName = () => {
    this.setState({ itemName: *menuList.name of the menu item that I hover over* })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <Menu menuList={this.menuList} />
        <ItemName itemName={this.state.itemName} />
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

**Child 1 - Menu**

```
const menu = (menuList) => (
  <>
    {menuList.map((item) => (
      <MenuItem {...item} menuList={menuList} key={item.name} />
    ))}
  </>
);
```

**Child 2 - MenuItem**

```
const menuItem = ({ name, icon }) => (
  <div data-item-name={name}>
    {icon}
  </div>
);
```

**Child 3 - ItemName**

```
const itemName = (itemName) => (
  <p>{ itemName }</p>
);
```

My idea was that I should probably make the MenuItem a class component and inside it create a method that would pass the {name} up to the parent, where it would be intercepted by the getItemName method, which would then update the state, but I have run out of ideas on how to achieve that.

Should I be doing this with Redux? Or maybe there's an easier way, which I didn't think about?

Comment: imho, `redux` would do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**MenuContainer**

```
class MenuContainer extends Component {

  onMouseOverEvent(name){
    this.setState({ itemName: name })
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <Menu
 menuList={this.menuList}  
onMouseOverEvent = {this.onMouseOverEvent}/> //passed event hanlder onMouseOverEvent
            <ItemName itemName={this.state.itemName} />
          </>
        )
      }
    }
```

**Menu**

```
    const Menu = ({menuList,onMouseOverEvent}) => (
      <>
        {menuList.map((item) => (
          <MenuItem {...item} menuList={menuList} key={item.name}  
onMouseOverEvent={onMouseOverEvent}/> //passed onMouseOverEvent as it is here 
        ))}
      </>
    );
```

**MenuItem**

```
    const MenuItem = ({ name, icon ,onMouseOverEvent}) => (
      <div data-item-name={name}
 onMouseOver={()=>onMouseOverEvent(name)}>//used to call onMouseOver Event
        {icon}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: This! I was literally one word away from solving this myself. I forgot to pass the argument 'name' (duh). Thanks! :)

Comment: @NorweskiDrwal nice,Please upvote it . if its working for you

Answer (score 0):

1. Do the `menuList.map(item)` in the parent, and pass to Menu a
   callback that will be called when the item is hovered-on. This
   callBack will have the item as a parameter.
2. Change `Menu` to display only one menu item. When that item is hovered-on, the callback will be called with the item as a parameter. Set a state variable that will hold this item.
3. `menuItem` will be called with this state variable.